# Анимирование scrollTop с jquery easing

Tags: jquery, javascript, html, css

Всех с Новым Годом!

Я делаю вот так:

```
$("#utop").click(function() {
        $("html,body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 200, 'easieEaseInOutCirc');
        return false;
    });
```

и код перестает работать. Если убрать 'easieEaseInOutCirc', то все норм. Но я хочу с такой анимашкой) Помогите пожалуйста, как это сделать правильно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А вы уверены, что правильно написали название динамики? Может я чего пропустил, [но на офф.сайте я такой не нашел](http://jqueryui.com/effect/#easing). Наиболее близкая динамика по названию - "**easeInOutCirc**". И да, для работы необходимо подключить jQuery UI.

Comment: Есть такая. В жругих местах то работает) А тут ничего не пашет

Comment: @inferus-vv, Хм... Возможно, что динамика не стандартная, но тогда должен быть какой-то плагин, обеспечивающий её работу. А что значит "В других местах то работает"? На вашем сайте работает или же вы находили примеры в инете? И еще... Может первая буква **"i"** лишнняя и надо писать "easeEaseInOutCirc"?

Answer (score 0):

easieEaseInOutCirc опишите в отдельную функции и включите её как callback.